# How to redirect to a page in Jasig's CAS from my own app's implementation of Spring's "AuthenticationUserDetailsService"?

Tags: spring, spring-security, cas, spring-security-oauth2

I've been searching for a day now, and I'm having so much problem, I dont know much about how Spring security and CAS.

Anyway, we use CAS for our login and authentication, after successfully logging in, it will redirect it to the our web-app then I need to check if the user has this permission, if not, I need to redirect it again to a customized page in CAS.

I tried throwing an exception, but I cannot handle it via Spring MVC exceptionhandling since Spring security is separate from MVC.

How can I do this?

Note: I have to do this exact sequence, CAS login > Authentication in our webapp (AuthenticationUserDetailsService) > redirect to a page in CAS if user is to agree to something if they're not allowed for now.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that when the user is authenticated in CAS and not authorized in your application, you would want to logout the user. With this assumption in mind, you can do that following,

CAS Login > Application checks for permission > If not permitted, redirect page to CAS logout.

You can then customize cas logout jsp page to display message you like.